# MUI Data Grid - How to access the grid API in the column definition

Tags: material-ui, datagrid, mui-datatable

In `mui v5`, in the `sortCompartor` function we had the possibility to catch the api in the parameters. It will be depreciated and I would like to know if there is another way to get the API.

I would need it in order to access the whole row data in the comparator.